# Trying to prevent wordwrap in CSS for title while working with WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, word-wrap

I have a website where I am working with a Wordpress theme that I am trying to modify.  If you go the site

```
http://66.147.244.132/~dokkanca/
```

and scroll down to where it says, "Ramadan specials through August 10th", you'll notice that the title bar which is in the form of a ribbon wraps to the next line.  I don't want this, but I can't figure out how to prevent this.  I've spent a lot of time trying to change parameters within my relevant CSS code but unfortunately I have not been successful.  Can someone please show me how to correct this so that the ribbon around the title goes straight across, and NOT wrap to the next line?  In my wordpress options, this title within the ribbon is referred to as, "Bottom slider title".  Below is my relevant CSS code:

```
.home-title{width:265px;color:#ffffff;font-family:'Merienda One', sans-serif;font-size:18px;text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.6);position:relative;padding:0px 0px 4px 10px;margin:0;}
.home-img{margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;display:block;overflow: hidden;border:2px solid #e9e9e9;}
.home-img .mask{width: 100%;height:100%;position: absolute;overflow: hidden;top:0;left:0;}
.home-img span.link-img {background:url("images/link-img.png") no-repeat 0 0;
   display:block;
   width:31px;
   height:37px;
   text-indent:-9999px;
   margin-left:45%;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-160px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-160px);
   -o-transform: translateY(-160px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-160px);
   transform: translateY(-160px);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.home-img:hover span.link-img{-webkit-transform: translateY(45px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(45px);
   -o-transform: translateY(45px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(45px);
   transform: translateY(45px);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.4s linear;
   transition: all 0.4s linear;}


.home-img, .post_image img, .img-left-post img{-webkit-transition: border-color 0.5s ease;-moz-transition: border-color 0.5s ease;-o-transition: border-color 0.5s ease;transition: border-color 0.5s ease;display: block;position: relative;}
.home-img:hover, .post_image:hover img, .img-left-post img:hover{-webkit-transition: border-color 0.5s ease;-moz-transition: border-color 0.5s ease;-o-transition: border-color 0.5s ease;transition: border-color 0.5s ease;}
.home-img .mask, .post_image .mask2{background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);-ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";   filter: alpha(opacity=0); opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.3s;-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.3s;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.3s;-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.3s;transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.3s;}
.home-img:hover .mask, .post_image:hover .mask2{-ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";filter: alpha(opacity=100);opacity: 1;-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;}

.home-bottom{margin-top:30px;}

.text-right{float:right;display:block;}

.home-bottom .home-title{margin-bottom:40px;}
.home-time{font-size:11px;color:#858585;font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; font-style:italic;}
.home-post-title{padding:0;margin-bottom:5px;}
.home-post-title a{font-size:14px;}
```

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrapping because you set .home-title to have `width:265px;`. Increase the value and it will solve your problem.
**Edit:** to not disturb the other elements with .home-title, see if you can assign that element a second class, with a new width value, > 265px.
Yet another option would be a rule like: `.container .span8 .home-title {width: put new width here}`

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  I did try to increase the .home-title to have a width greater than 265px, but unfortunately it is indeed disturbing the other elements.  When you say to assign that element a second class with a new width value >265px, can you please show me how to add a second class to the element .home-title so it is in isolation of the other elements?  I am a bit of a newbie to css and am afraid of disturbing the other elements as you correctly pointed out.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, can you just add the last rule I mentioned, replacing xxx with desired width, `.container .span8 .home-title {width: xxxpx;}` in the style.css file of the theme ? Add it at the end of the file. It's a very specific rule that should only target the area you mentioned. No other modifications should be needed, just clear your browser cache after the modification. Write back if it still doesn't work.